# Reversing a string using with a recursive function in C++

Tags: c++, string, function, recursion

To explore my understanding of recursion, I am attempting to reverse a string by use of a recursive function. This seems like it should be more simple than it is for me right now. Can any one tell me what I am doing wrong. When I execute the code below, it results in a blank line. I looked around on here for similar topics but every thing is in other languages... much to my surprise.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


/**
    Recursivly reverses a string
    @param return last_char, the last character currently in the string
    @param go, the recursive function to return the character and continue     within the function
    **/
char string_reverse(string word)
{

    if (word.length()-1 > 0)
    {
    char last_char = word[word.length()-1];
    word.erase(word.length()-1);
    char go = string_reverse(word);
    return go;

    }

else 
    return false;

}


int main()
{
cout << "Enter a string: ";
string input;
getline(cin, input);
string last;
last = last + string_reverse(input);
cout << last << endl;

/*char fig = string_reverse(input, fig);
cout << fig << endl;
*/

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return string, also you need to prepend extracted char to returned value

```
string string_reverse(string word)
{
    if (word.length() - 1 > 0)
    {
        char last_char = word[word.length()-1];
        word.erase(word.length()-1);
        string go = string_reverse(word);
        return go.insert(0, 1, last_char);
    }
    else
        return "";
}
```

Comment: changing char go = string_reverse(word); to a string reversed it all except the first letter. Thanks. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

In `string_reverse`, you should return the `last character` + `string_reverse(word)` + `first character`.

In your `else`, return an empty string so you don't run into typing errors.

When you call the function, don't do anything else to `word`, just call `string_reverse(word)`

To put it all together:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


/**
    Recursivly reverses a string
    @param return last_char, the last character currently in the string
    @param go, the recursive function to return the character and continue
    within the function
    **/
string string_reverse(string word)
{

    if (word.length()-1 > 0)
    {
    string first_char = word.substr(0,1);
    string last_char = word.substr(word.size()-1,1);
    string middle = word.substr(1, word.size()-2);
    return last_char + string_reverse(middle) + first_char;

    }

else 
    return "";

}


int main()
{
cout << "Enter a string: ";
string input;
getline(cin, input);
cout << string_reverse(input); << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

However this will fail for odd-numbered letter counts. "c" will output "cc". I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: Has some bugs in it, but thanks for the insight. I'll mess with it.

Comment: Yeah sorry bout that. I didn't actually run this.

Answer (score 2):

`string_reverse()` returns `char`. You cannot possibly return the reverse of a string using a single `char`.

On top of that, the logic in `string_reverse()` is a *long* way from doing anything approaching reversing a string.

Comment: Cant you put each char together then cast it to a string?

Answer (score 0):

your reverse body will not work at all. The idea to reverse is as follows:

```
If the string len is 1, return it.
Otherwise,
   Remove the first character.
   Recursively reverse the remaining string.
   Add the first character above to the reversed string.
   Return the new string.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you return string, the shortest version you can get will be this:

```
std::string string_reverse(const std::string& str)
{
  return str.size() > 1? string_reverse(str.substr(1)) + str[0] : str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minor tweak to one of the answers above, that handles strings of either even or odd length:

```
string reverse (string str)
{

if (str.length() == 0)
    return "";
else
    if (str.length() == 1)
        return str.substr(0,1);
    else
    {
        string first_char = str.substr(0,1);
        string last_char = str.substr(str.size()-1,1);
        string middle = str.substr(1, str.size()-2);
        return last_char + reverse(middle) + first_char;
    }
 }
```

Strings of length 0 and those of length 1 must each be handled separately from the recursive case.

Answer (score 0):

Found an easy way to rewrite code without all the function calls that works for odd or even number strings. Seems more efficient please note if there is any bugs, this was a homework question I solved. Would love any comments to correct issues

```html
string R_reverse(string input)
{
 if (input.length() == 0)
  return input;
 else
 {
  string old = input.substr(0,1);
  string newstr = input.substr(1, (input.length() - 1));
  return R_reverse(newstr) + old;
 }
}
```